# XPath with specific following sibling case

Tags: xpath

I have structure that looks something like this

```
<p>
   <br>
       <b>Text to fetch </b>
   <br>
       "Some random text"
       <b>Text not to fetch</b>
```

I need XPath that will allow me to fetch following sibling of the *br* element only if there is no text between *br* element and his following sibling.

If I do something like this

```
//br/following-sibling::b/text()[1]
```

It will fetch both `Text to fetch` and `Text not to fetch`, while I only need `Text to fetch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible XPath :

```
//br/following-sibling::node()[normalize-space()][1][self::b]/text()
```

brief explanation:

- `//br/following-sibling::node()`: find all nodes that is following-sibling of `br` element, where the nodes are..
- `[normalize-space()]`: not empty (whitespace only), then..
- `[1]`: for each `br` found, take only the first of such node, then..
- `[self::b]`: check if the node is a `b` element, then if it is a `b` element..
- `/text()`: return text node that is child of the `b` element

Answer (score 1):

Try below XPath to avoid matching `b` nodes with preceding sibling text:

```
//br/following-sibling::b[not(preceding-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space()])]/text()
```